# Excel VBA: How do I open an Excel file without running macro but want macros to run when I activate workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have the below sub in `ThisWorkbook`. I would like to run this sub "SubName" whenever I activate this workbook, but **don't want** the macro to run when I open the file (it currently runs the "SubName" which causes an error because data takes about 5 seconds to load before the macro functions properly)

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

SubName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before `SubName` :

```
Do Until Application.Ready = True
DoEvents: Loop
```